# WIX: how to call custom action exe with parameters

Tags: wix, custom-action

I want to call a .exe under PCMINSTALLDIR with parameters so I can use the parameters passed in the .exe. When I run the installer, it said my installer has a problem. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? And how to debug it? Thanks.

WiX file:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="$(var.PlatformProgramFilesFolder)" Name="PFiles">
        <Directory Id="CompanyDir" Name="ABC">
          <Directory Id="PCMINSTALLDIR" Name="ClientMonitor">
            <Directory Id="STDSCIPTSDIR" Name="standard_scripts">
            </Directory>

            <Directory Id="CSTMSCIPTSDIR" Name="custom_scripts">
            </Directory>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
```

.....

```
 <CustomAction Id="ChangeConfigExe" Directory="PCMINSTALLDIR" ExeCommand ='PcmConfigExe.exe Hello' Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="check" />


    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="ChangeConfigExe" Before="InstallFinalize" /> 
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: launch with the msi commandline: msiexec /i <your msi> /L*V log.txt then take a look through the log for references to the custom action

Comment: Most likely there's nothing wrong with your WiX, but the program isn't running because it has missing dependencies and doesn't start, or it starts up and crashes. That CA is deferred, which means it's probably running with the system account with an unanticipated working directory. In other words all the testing you do as the logged on user doesn't mean it'll work when running with the system account.